# how to link a specific CSS file to the master page based on the browser Culture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I am new to asp.net (C#) and I am working in a multilingual project. I need to link a specific style sheet based on selected language in the user browser .. how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this in your master page

```
<% if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName == "en-US") { %>
 <link href="~/Styles/english.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% } else { %>
 <link href="~/Styles/otherlang.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% } %>
```

a complete language identifier list can be found here : http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html

Comment: It worked .. thank you I just had to change "en-US" to "English (United States)"